# Error summing up the array values in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am new to Swift. Trying this code in Playground and get the error (see description below) Can you, please, point me to the right direction - where to look for the solution? Thanks in advance.

```
func randomSet(num: Int, max: Int) -> Array<Double> {

    var randArray = Array<Double>()

    for index in 0...num {
        randArray[index] = Double(arc4random_uniform(max+1))
    }

ERROR: var sum = randArray.reduce(0) {$0 + $1}

    for index in 0...num {
        randArray[index] = randArray[index] / Double(sum) * Double(max)
    }

    return randArray
}

test = randomSet(10, 100)
```

On the line marked with word ERROR, I get this:

Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your post to be more descriptive of the problem. *How can I correct this?* will be absolutely meaningless when it turns up in a search result by a future user here. Your title should describe the problem or contain a descriptive question that has some relevance. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `0...num` *includes* the range end, so that will give you an array with `num+1` elements. You probably want to `0 ..< num` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually caused by attempting to append values in `randArray` using subscripting. You should use `append` instead:

```
for _ in 0...num {
    randArray.append(Double(arc4random_uniform(max+1)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is not from the function reduce,  but in initialization of your array, you can't access to index before initialization. The code below fix the bug.

```
  for index in 0...num {
    randArray.append(Double(arc4random_uniform(max+1)))
  }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, Hamza, that made even more clear! In other words, I have to populate my array with some values before I can use index. Got it.